# Failure using .this on callback on loader

Tags: android

Trying to use a loader, but it's giving me error on "this" for callback function to refresh my listview. I've included my function for deleting notes in a simple notepad-app. Gives me the following run-error:

> ```
> Error:(77, 47) error: method restartLoader in class LoaderManager cannot be applied to given types;
> required: int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks<D>
> found: int,<null>,<anonymous OnClickListener>
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) D
> (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to LoaderCallbacks<D>)
> where D is a type-variable:
> D extends Object declared in method <D>restartLoader(int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks<D>)
> ```

```
private void deleteAllNotes() {

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener =
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                    if (button == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                                getContentResolver().delete(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,null, null);

                        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0,null,this);

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.all_deleted),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.are_you_sure))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
            .show();

}
```

Comment: I guess your `MainActivity` implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<>`? Ain't it? Not your `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Use `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0,null,MainActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that method, `this` refers to the current instance of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` (aka your `dialogClickListener` variable). You need to pass the method an instance of `LoaderCallbacks`, and `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` is not.

Probably your Activity implements `LoaderCallbacks`. Assuming your activity is named `MainActivity`, you can replace `this` with `MainActivity.this` to get a reference to your activity instead of the click listener.

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0,null,MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. I'm quite new, so this was part of a tutorial that never fully explained all the steps. So that's because it's inside a fragment? So I simply had to direct the action towards the MainActivity.java-file?